# What happens to the history of git pull requests when a new branch with the same name of an old branch is pushed

Tags: git, github, pull-request

Szenario:

- branch "A" created
- pull request for "A" is created
- branch "A" is deleted
- new branch "A" is created
- Question 1: Is it possible to push the same branch name again?
- if yes Question 2: do the commits from new branch "A" get moved to the pull request for the old branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) yes it is possible to push the same branch name after a branch is deleted 2) no, any pull requests for the former branch of the same name would not be updated.

When Branch A is deleted, the open pull requests to merge Branch A somewhere else are closed. If instead of deleting and recreating branch A you did a force push to update branch A (assuming a divergent history of course), then the pull requests would be updated. (Standard warnings of the potential danger the force push apply of course).